# dynamodb atomic increment with condition

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I would like to increment a counter in a row only if a certain attribute doesnt exist in the row. I tried this

```
response = dynamodb.update_item(TableName=table_name, 
        Key={'id':{'S': id}}, 
        UpdateExpression='SET #att = #att + :inc',  
        ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(#a)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#att": "counter", "#a": "attribute"}, 
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':inc': {'N': '1'}}, 
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
```

but I get an error

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the 
UpdateItem operation: The provided expression refers to an 
attribute that does not exist in the item
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "ADD" expression instead of "SET" will create the counter attribute (if it does not exist) then add the value: [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD)

The query code may look like:

```cs
response = dynamodb.update_item(TableName=table_name, 
        Key={'id':{'S': id}}, 
        UpdateExpression='ADD #att :inc',  
        ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(#a)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#att": "counter", "#a": "attribute"}, 
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':inc': {'N': '1'}}, 
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `attribute` exists on the item but `counter` doesn’t, so you can’t access the current value of `counter` to increment it.